# How to prove $f$ is differentiable at $c$ iff $g(c) = h(c)$ and $g′(c) = h′(c)$.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

> Let $D$ be an open interval, and $g, h$ are both functions from $D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and $c \in D$.  Define
> \begin{equation}
>   f(x) =
>     \begin{cases}
>       g(x) & \text{if $x < c$}\\
>       h(x) & \text{if $x \geq c$}\\
>     \end{cases}       
> \end{equation}
> Prove that $f$ is differentiable at $c$ if and only if $g(c) = h(c)$ and $g′(c) = h′(c)$.

Forward: $f$ is differentiable at $c$ $\Rightarrow$ $f$ is continuous at $c$ $\Rightarrow$ $g(c) = h(c)$ $\Rightarrow$ $g'(c) - h'(c) =  \lim_{x \to c} \frac{g(x) - g(c) - (h(x) - h(c))}{x-c} = \lim_{x \to c} \frac{g(x) - h(x)}{x-c} = 0 $ as $g(c) = h(c)$.

However, I have no clue how to do the backward direction. Could anyone give me some hints?

Comment: This is not true as written. Consider $g(x) = -|x-c|$ and $h(x) = |x-c|$, so that neither $g'(c)$ nor $h'(c)$ exist, but $f(x) = x - c$ is differentiable at $c$. The condition should instead be that the left derivative of $g$ is equal to the right derivative of $h$ at $c$

Comment: Yes, and this is why the "only if" implication fails. That is $f$ being differentiable at $c$ does not imply that $g'(c) = h'(c)$, since these may not exist.

Comment: Actually, it's not even necessarily true that $g(c) = h(c)$.

Answer (score 1):

For the forward direction you are assuming the existence of $g'(c)$ and $h'(c)$ in your argument.

Backward direction: The condition $g'(c)=h'(c)$ assumes that $g$ and $h$ are differentiable at $c$.

First note that $g(c)=h(c)$ makes $f$ continuous at $c$ with $f(c)=g(c)=h(c)$. $\lim_{x\to c+} \frac {f(x)-f(c)} {x-c}=\lim_{x\to c+} \frac {g(x)-g(c)} {x-c}=g'(c)$ and $\lim_{x\to c-} \frac {f(x)-f(c)} {x-c}=\lim_{x\to c-} \frac {h(x)-h(c)} {x-c}=h'(c)$ so the left-and right derivatives are equal.